# Oracle SQL find columns with different values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dataframe, validation

I have two tables A and B both with some millions rows and around one hundred columns.

**I want to find which columns have different observations without the need of listing the names of all the columns.**

For example, suppose column `ID` is the primary key in both tables. And that table A is

```
ID | col1 | col2
----------------
1  | 123  | 101
2  | 456  | 111
```

while table B is

```
ID | col1 | col2
----------------
1  | 123  | 101
2  | 456  | 222
```

The result of my query would be something about `col2`. I'm indifferent if a table based on observations form tabla A or B or whatever. What I would like in the query is to avoid to list all the columns since they are a lot. I am not interested in knowing the rows whose columns have different values, only the columns.

**EDIT:**

Consider these assumptions:

- First, assume that the columns in the two tables have the same name. I would prefer something that works without this assumption but I'm more than ok with it.
- Second, the columns of the tables are only numeric. Again, this is assumed to simplify.

Thanks!

Comment: Let's start with the simplest questions. Say table A has a column `HIRE_DATE` and table B does not. What do you want shown in this case? The difference here is not in the data (for one `ID` or another) - it's a difference between the tables themselves. Then: What if both tables have a column `USER_CODE`, but it's a `varchar2` column in one table but `number` in the other? Obviously, you won't be able to compare them.

Comment: Thank for the question @mathguy. In the first case ideally I wil get the name of `HIRE_DATE`, but also excluding cases with different colum names is fine to start. In the second case always assume that columns in common share the same type.

Comment: how about select  column_name from all tab_cols where table_name = 'table1' intersect select column_name from all tab.cols where table_name = table2.  once you have the column names use dymanic sql (execute immediate) to compose your select statement with the columns from the query

Comment: @BryanDellinger I understand that your query returns the columns in common between the two tables. This is already great, thanks! However, how do I then use it to solve my problem?

Comment: think you would need to use pl/sql so your cursor is the query to get the columns. then make your query as a string and do a loop of your cursor and append in your columns.  then use execute immediate to run the dynamic sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from a colleague and I think it's worth posting it for future users. He used PL/SQL and a loop on the two tables `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 10000

DECLARE
    v_sql_text     VARCHAR2(300);
    n_contador     NUMBER;
    n_contador_2   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR x IN (
        SELECT
            column_name
        FROM
            user_tab_columns
        WHERE
            table_name IN (
                'TABLE_A'
            )
    ) LOOP
        v_sql_text := 'SELECT /*+ PARALLEL 32 */ count(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT('
                      || x.column_name
                      || ') FROM TABLE_A MINUS SELECT DISTINCT('
                      || x.column_name
                      || ') FROM TABLE_B)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_text
    INTO n_contador;
    v_sql_text := 'SELECT /*+ PARALLEL 32 */ count(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT('
                  || x.column_name
                  || ') FROM TABLE_B MINUS SELECT DISTINCT('
                  || x.column_name
                  || ') FROM TABLE_A)';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_text
    INTO n_contador_2;
    IF n_contador != 0 OR n_contador_2 != 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(x.column_name || ' is different');
    END IF;

END LOOP;
END;
/
```